# Oracle SQL check whether a date is between today's date and another date

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way by which I can simplify the below using `BETWEEN` ?

```
select  * 
from support 
where 
(datereceived <= sysdate) and (datereceived >= add_months (sysdate,-3));
```

Many thanks

Comment: By writing`between` instead of `>=` and `<=`. Please, check the syntax [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/BETWEEN-Condition.html#GUID-868A7C9D-EDF9-44E7-91B5-C3F69E503CCB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `datereceived` probably refers only to something that has already happened, I don't think you need to check that there is no future date.

So, a simpler comparison would be:

```
where datereceived >= add_months(sysdate, -3)
```

Then, you might not realize that `sysdate` has a time component.  And you probably don't care about specific times.  So, you might actually intend:

```
where datereceived >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write -

```
SELECT *
  FROM support
 WHERE datereceived BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3) AND SYSDATE;
```